# Prestashop - Backoffice - Add Order show address

Tags: php, prestashop, customization

When I am in backoffice and try to add an order and search for my customers I would like to show the customer's address in the little box.
 [AddOrder-Search for Customer screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jO5Dk.jpg)

in /themes/default/template/controllers/orders/form.tpl i have:

```
 function searchCustomers()
   {
..........................
            html += '<div class="panel-heading">'+this.company+' '+this.firstname+' '+this.lastname;
            html += '<span class="pull-right">#'+this.id_customer+'</span></div>';
            html += '<span>'+this.email+'</span><br/>';
            html += '<span>'+this.addresses+'</span><br/>';
```

But that just shows as "undefined"
so i think i need to add something in the controllers/admin/AdminCustomersController.php (searchCustomers) but i am not sure.

Can somebody tell me what code am i missing?

I am using Prestashop 1.6.1.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display the data, you need to get the data if it's not there. In this case, the this.addresses notifies undefined, because it doesn't "exist".

You can use this in override/controllers/admin/AdminCustomerControllers.php

```
public function ajaxProcessSearchCustomers()
    {
        $searches = explode(' ', Tools::getValue('customer_search'));
        $customers = array();
        $searches = array_unique($searches);
        foreach ($searches as $search) {
            if (!empty($search) && $results = Customer::searchByName($search, 50)) {
                foreach ($results as $result) {
                    if ($result['active']) {
                        $customer = new Customer($result['id_customer']);
                        $addresses = $customer->getAddresses($this->context->language->id);
                        $result['addresses'] = '';
                        if(is_array($addresses) and !empty($addresses))
                        {
                            foreach ($addresses as $address) {
                                $result['addresses'] .= $address['alias'].'<br />';
                            }
                        }
                        $customers[$result['id_customer']] = $result;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        if (count($customers)) {
            $to_return = array(
                'customers' => $customers,
                'found' => true
            );
        } else {
            $to_return = array('found' => false);
        }

        $this->content = Tools::jsonEncode($to_return);
    }
```

This will define the addresses (only the aliases of the addresses, if you need more just change the line `$result['addresses'] .= $address['alias'].'<br />';`.

Don't forget to set the correct class `class AdminCustomersController extends AdminCustomersControllerCore` and then delete the file `cache/class_index.php`